# SQL JSON - Append Json to Json

Tags: json, sql-server

I Have this json:

```
{"keyvalue": {"head": {"id": ""},"column": {"id": ""},"degrees": {"id": ""}}}
```

How do i add this json to the key "keyvalue":

```
"somekey": { "id" : "" }
```

so my json looks like this:

```
{"keyvalue": {"head": {"id": ""},"column": {"id": ""},"degrees": {"id": ""}, "somekey": { "id" : "" }}}
```

i tried this:

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY('{"keyvalue": {"head": {"id": ""},"column": {"id": ""},"degrees": {"id": ""}}}', 'append $', json_query(N' {"somekey": {"id" : ""}}'))
FROM PL_Table
WHERE PL_Id = 6;
```

but nothing changed

UPDATE

i have this now:

```
update PL_PageLayout
set PL_Json = json_modify('{

"keyvalue": {
    "obj1": {
        "id": ""
    },
    "obj2": {
        "id": ""
    },
    "obj3": {
        "id": ""
    }
}


}', 'append $.keyvalue.content', '{"id" : "ddd"}')
FROM PL_PageLayout
WHERE PL_Id = 6;
```

Output is:

```
{"keyvalue": {"obj1": {"id": ""},"obj2": {"id": ""},"obj3": {"id": ""},"content":["{\"id\" : \"ddd\"}"]}}
```

but the

```
"content":["{\"id\" : \"ddd\"}"]
```

needs to be

```
"content":{\"id\" : \"ddd\"}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update rows in `PL_Table`?  A SELECT query won't do that.  You have to use an UPDATE.

Comment: im just using select to see the results, ill use update later

Comment: i see what you mean David Browne i have something working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this result is that with `append` optional [modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments), the new value is appended to the array referenced by the `path`. You also need to use `JSON_QUERY()` to get a properly formatted `JSON`, because `JSON_MODIFY` escapes all special characters in the new value if the type of the value is `varchar` or `nvarchar`.

You may try with the following approach, without using `append`:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"keyvalue": {"head": {"id": ""},"column": {"id": ""},"degrees": {"id": ""}}}'

SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
   @json,
   '$.keyvalue.somekey',
   JSON_QUERY(N'{"id" : ""}')
)
```

Result:

```
{"keyvalue": {"head": {"id": ""},"column": {"id": ""},"degrees": {"id": ""},"somekey":{"id" : ""}}}
```

Comment: that result is close the output is: {     "keyvalue": {    "obj1": {     "id": ""    },    "obj2": {     "id": ""    },    "obj3": {     "id": ""    }   ,"content":"{\"id\" : \"ddd\"}"}      } but the quotes i dont need why are they there?

Comment: @redoc01 Use `JSON_QUERY()` to prevent escaping.